# How can I update a Boundedfield with numeric data type in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following VB.net code that updates the row from Boundedfields using the identifying the cell number.

```
Protected Sub grvPos_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles grvPos.RowUpdating

    Dim cs As String
    Dim con As iDB2Connection
    Dim sql As String
    Dim cmd As iDB2Command
    Dim valDate As Integer
    Dim portCode As String
    Dim secCode As String
    Dim valType As String
    Dim portName As String
    Dim ISINno As String
    Dim secName As String
    Dim secCcyAbbr As String
    Dim trxBccy As Decimal
    Dim quantity As Integer
    Dim mktPrice As Integer
    Dim avgCost As Integer
    Dim avgBvalSc As Integer
    Dim avgBvalBc As Integer
    Dim intAmtSc As Integer
    Dim intAmtBc As Integer
    Dim gr As GridViewRow

    gr = grvPos.Rows(e.RowIndex)

    valDate = grvPos.DataKeys(gr.RowIndex).Values("VALN_DATE")
    portCode = grvPos.DataKeys(gr.RowIndex).Values("PORT_CODE").ToString()
    secCode = grvPos.DataKeys(gr.RowIndex).Values("SEC_CODE").ToString()
    valType = grvPos.Rows(gr.RowIndex).Cells(2).ToString()
    portName = grvPos.Rows(gr.RowIndex).Cells(4).ToString()
    ISINno = grvPos.Rows(gr.RowIndex).Cells(6).ToString()
    secName = grvPos.Rows(gr.RowIndex).Cells(7).ToString()
    secCcyAbbr = grvPos.Rows(gr.RowIndex).Cells(8).ToString()
    trxBccy = grvPos.Rows(gr.RowIndex).Cells(9).ToString()
    quantity = CInt(grvPos.Rows(gr.RowIndex).Cells(10).ToString())
    mktPrice = CInt(grvPos.Rows(gr.RowIndex).Cells(11).ToString())
    avgCost = CInt(grvPos.Rows(gr.RowIndex).Cells(14).ToString())
    avgBvalSc = CInt(grvPos.Rows(gr.RowIndex).Cells(15).ToString())
    avgBvalBc = CInt(grvPos.Rows(gr.RowIndex).Cells(16).ToString())
    intAmtSc = CInt(grvPos.Rows(gr.RowIndex).Cells(17).ToString())
    intAmtBc = CInt(grvPos.Rows(gr.RowIndex).Cells(18).ToString())

    cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionStringDB2").ConnectionString
    con = New iDB2Connection(cs)
    sql = "MERGE INTO GICPFDTA.OPTR_POS_FIX O " &
          "USING OLYFPRO.FDBVAL F ON O.SEC_CODE = F.VLVALR " &
          "AND (O.VALN_DATE = @VALN_DATE) " &
          "AND (O.PORT_CODE = @PORT_CODE) " &
          "AND (O.SEC_CODE = @SEC_CODE) " &
          "WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET " &
          "O.VAL_TYPE = @VAL_TYPE " &
          ",O.PORT_SNAME = @PORT_SNAME " &
          ",O.ISIN_NO = @ISIN_NO " &
          ",O.SEC_SNAME = @SEC_SNAME " &
          ",O.SEC_CCY_ABBR = @SEC_CCY_ABBR " &
          ",O.TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE = @TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE " &
          ",O.QUANTITY = @QUANTITY " &
          ",O.MKT_PRICE = @MKT_PRICE " &
          ",O.AVG_COST = @AVG_COST " &
          ",O.AVG_BVAL_SC = @AVG_BVAL_SC " &
          ",O.AVG_BVAL_BC = @AVG_BVAL_BC " &
          ",O.INT_AMT_SC = @INT_AMT_SC " &
          ",O.INT_AMT_BC = @INT_AMT_BC " &
          ",O.MVAL_AMT_SC = ROUND(@QUANTITY * @MKT_PRICE / (" &
          "CASE " &
          "WHEN F.VLGTI = 100 " &
          "THEN 100 " &
            "ELSE 1 " &
          "END" &
           "), 3) " &
           ",O.MVAL_AMT_BC = ROUND(@QUANTITY * @MKT_PRICE / (" &
          "CASE " &
          "WHEN F.VLGTI = 100 " &
            "THEN 100 " &
          "ELSE 1 " &
          "END" &
          ") / @TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE, 3)"
    cmd = New iDB2Command(sql, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VALN_DATE", valDate)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PORT_CODE", portCode)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEC_CODE", secCode)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL_TYPE", valType)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PORT_SNAME", portName)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISIN_NO", ISINno)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEC_SNAME", secName)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEC_CCY_ABBR", secCcyAbbr)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE", trxBccy)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE", trxBccy)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QUANTITY", quantity)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QUANTITY", quantity)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QUANTITY", quantity)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MKT_PRICE", mktPrice)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MKT_PRICE", mktPrice)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MKT_PRICE", mktPrice)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AVG_COST", avgCost)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AVG_BVAL_SC", avgBvalSc)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AVG_BVAL_BC", avgBvalBc)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INT_AMT_SC", intAmtSc)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INT_AMT_BC", intAmtBc)

    Try
        lblError.Text = ""

        Using con
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            gridLoad()
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```

The trxBccy variable is Numeric data type, but I specified it as Decimal, I also tried Integer data type. 
When I try to update a row I get the following error:

Conversion from string "System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataCo" to type 'Decimal' is not valid.

I appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to capture the values from the bounded fields using the below code.

```
    Protected Sub grvPos_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles grvPos.RowUpdating

    Dim cs As String
    Dim con As iDB2Connection
    Dim sql As String
    Dim cmd As iDB2Command
    Dim valDate As Integer
    Dim portCode As String
    Dim secCode As String
    Dim valType As String
    Dim portName As String
    Dim ISINno As String
    Dim secName As String
    Dim secCcyAbbr As String
    Dim trxBccy As Decimal
    Dim quantity As Decimal
    Dim mktPrice As Decimal
    Dim avgCost As Decimal
    Dim avgBvalSc As Decimal
    Dim avgBvalBc As Decimal
    Dim intAmtSc As Decimal
    Dim intAmtBc As Decimal
    Dim gr As GridViewRow

    gr = grvPos.Rows(e.RowIndex)



    valDate = grvPos.DataKeys(gr.RowIndex).Values("VALN_DATE")
    portCode = grvPos.DataKeys(gr.RowIndex).Values("PORT_CODE").ToString()
    secCode = grvPos.DataKeys(gr.RowIndex).Values("SEC_CODE").ToString()
    valType = e.NewValues("VAL_TYPE").ToString()
    portName = e.NewValues("PORT_SNAME").ToString()
    ISINno = e.NewValues("ISIN_NO").ToString()
    secName = e.NewValues("SEC_SNAME").ToString()
    secCcyAbbr = e.NewValues("SEC_CCY_ABBR").ToString()
    trxBccy = e.NewValues("TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE").ToString()
    quantity = e.NewValues("QUANTITY").ToString()
    mktPrice = e.NewValues("MKT_PRICE").ToString()
    avgCost = e.NewValues("AVG_COST").ToString()
    avgBvalSc = e.NewValues("AVG_BVAL_SC").ToString()
    avgBvalBc = e.NewValues("AVG_BVAL_BC").ToString()
    intAmtSc = e.NewValues("INT_AMT_SC").ToString()
    intAmtBc = e.NewValues("INT_AMT_BC").ToString()

    cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionStringDB2").ConnectionString
    con = New iDB2Connection(cs)
    sql = "MERGE INTO GICPFDTA.OPTR_POS_FIX O " &
          "USING OLYFPRO.FDBVAL F ON O.SEC_CODE = F.VLVALR " &
          "AND (O.VALN_DATE = @VALN_DATE) " &
          "AND (O.PORT_CODE = @PORT_CODE) " &
          "AND (O.SEC_CODE = @SEC_CODE) " &
          "WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET " &
          "O.VAL_TYPE = @VAL_TYPE " &
          ",O.PORT_SNAME = @PORT_SNAME " &
          ",O.ISIN_NO = @ISIN_NO " &
          ",O.SEC_SNAME = @SEC_SNAME " &
          ",O.SEC_CCY_ABBR = @SEC_CCY_ABBR " &
          ",O.TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE = @TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE " &
          ",O.QUANTITY = @QUANTITY " &
          ",O.MKT_PRICE = @MKT_PRICE " &
          ",O.AVG_COST = @AVG_COST " &
          ",O.AVG_BVAL_SC = @AVG_BVAL_SC " &
          ",O.AVG_BVAL_BC = @AVG_BVAL_BC " &
          ",O.INT_AMT_SC = @INT_AMT_SC " &
          ",O.INT_AMT_BC = @INT_AMT_BC " &
          ",O.MVAL_AMT_SC = ROUND(@QUANTITY * @MKT_PRICE / (" &
          "CASE " &
          "WHEN F.VLGTI = 100 " &
          "THEN 100 " &
            "ELSE 1 " &
          "END" &
           "), 3) " &
           ",O.MVAL_AMT_BC = ROUND(@QUANTITY * @MKT_PRICE / (" &
          "CASE " &
          "WHEN F.VLGTI = 100 " &
            "THEN 100 " &
          "ELSE 1 " &
          "END" &
          ") / @TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE, 3)"
    cmd = New iDB2Command(sql, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VALN_DATE", valDate)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PORT_CODE", portCode)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEC_CODE", secCode)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL_TYPE", valType)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PORT_SNAME", portName)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISIN_NO", ISINno)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEC_SNAME", secName)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEC_CCY_ABBR", secCcyAbbr)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE", trxBccy)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE", trxBccy)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QUANTITY", quantity)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QUANTITY", quantity)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QUANTITY", quantity)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MKT_PRICE", mktPrice)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MKT_PRICE", mktPrice)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MKT_PRICE", mktPrice)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AVG_COST", avgCost)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AVG_BVAL_SC", avgBvalSc)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AVG_BVAL_BC", avgBvalBc)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INT_AMT_SC", intAmtSc)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INT_AMT_BC", intAmtBc)

    Try
        lblError.Text = ""

        Using con
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            grvPos.EditIndex = -1
            gridLoad()
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```